# find shortcode in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, nextgen-gallery

H

I want to be able to add an addition class to my BODY tag when the [slideshow] shortcode is found on the page that is loading? Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.  Add the following code to functions.php of your theme, and replace *'your-custom-body-class'* with the actual class name you want to add for posts and pages with [slideshow] shortcode.

```
<?php

function custom_body_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    if (isset($post->post_content) && false !== stripos($post->post_content, '[slideshow]')) {
        array_push($classes, 'your-custom-body-class');
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class', 'custom_body_class', 100, 1);
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked. I just had to change [slideshow] to [slideshow as it has attributes. thanks!